# how i fix SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code, and it's giving me a error, that says that an space is an invalid sytanx, look:

`from './getinput.py' import getInput as getInput`

and it says this error:

```
line 1
    from './getinput.py' import getInput as getInput
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i don't know what to do, could you guys give me some help? Here is some code if necessary, let's start with my main file:

```
def WhereDoIStart():
    print("Hi! How are you? Whats your name?")
    name = input()

    print('''Well, '''+name+''' i hope you're doing well! This here is not the text i have, but i can include it's features! it has somethings like this: "+", "-", "*", "/"''')
    getInput()

WhereDoIStart()
```

here i have what's in getinput.py:

```
def getInput():
    Userinput = input(">: ")
    return Userinput
```

Comment: `from .getinput import getInput`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of Python's import system

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Section 5.4.2 Submodules, translated into your example:
If there is the following folder structure

```
spam/
    __init__.py
    getinput.py
```

You could import the getinput module's function as follows:

```
from .getinput import getInput as getInput
```